# What is the best service worker strategy for create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

Every code update to the production build shows a white screen to the user until they refresh the page. What is the best service worker strategy for code updates to be pushed seamlessly to the user? (no page refresh or cache clearing necessary)

The default service worker behavior is not ideal. It seems that every production code update causes the browser to show a white screen until the user manually refreshes the page. I understand this may require something along the lines of sw-precache and implementing workbox for custom service worker functionality - that is all fine, and I've tried that out and have gotten those libraries running and working to the point that It still mimics the exact same behavior (so I think the project is essentially ready for the correct service worker to be implemented without ejecting). However, I'm still lost as to what is the best caching strategies/service worker to use to achieve my desired result?

Comment: If you've already gotten it working, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: It works only to the extent that I've gotten sw-precache and workbox up and running with the *same* default behavior. (forces user to refresh the page). I'd like advice on a strategy that causes NO white screen and production code updates to be applied seamlessly, no page refresh required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heyy Timothy!

I think you already found the answer to your question by now. I hope this answer will help future developers in their journey.

The strategies you are referring to are called caching strategies. Here's a list of commonly used ones:

- `networkOnly` – only fetch from the network
- `cacheOnly` – only fetch from cache
- `fastest` – fetch from both, and respond with whichever comes first
- `cacheFirst` – fetch from the cache, but also fetch from network and update cache

By default, CRA's service worker uses the `cache-first` strategy.

In your case, you have the possibility to choose between 2 strategies:

- `networkOnly`  Strategy

Pros: Will always render the latest version of the app (No white screen)

Cons: This will cause the user to fetch the app from the network every time.

- `networkFirst` Strategy

This strategy can be used in your case. You can set your SW to look out for a version update. If a new version is found, you can display a small toaster saying 'Hey there, a new version is available please click here to refresh'

---

You can also check the following links for more information:

- https://serviceworke.rs/caching-strategies.html
- https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-service-workers-and-caching-strategies-a6c1e1cbde03
- https://medium.com/@glukmann/let-users-know-when-you-have-updated-your-service-worker-in-create-react-app-b0c2701995b3